# How to getline from input file and put string and int to different array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to use c++ <#fstream> to input an file then
want get the String and Integer from given text file
and here is the given file content
Mary Brown      100 90  90
George Smith    90  30  50
Dale Barnes     80  78  82
Sally Dolittle  70  65  80
Conrad Bailer   60  58  71
What is the solution for get name and nubmer from this inputfile to different array
which is make it looks like

`numArry[1]=100;

numArry[2]=90;......

nameArry[1]=Mary Brown;

nameArry[2]=George Smith;`
cause at the end I want get average grade and grade letter for each person

```
cout << firstname << ' ' << lastname << " has an average of ";  
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << average <<   " which gives the letter grade of " << findLetterGrade(average) << endl;
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  You'll be thankful you did.

Answer (score 0):

As with most of these questions, I recommend you model each line (record) as a `class` or `struct`:

```
class Record
{
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;
  std::vector<int> grade_values;
};
```

The next step is to overload `operator>>` to read in a `Record`:

```
class Record
{
  public:
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.first_name;
  input >> r.last_name;
  int grade;
  input >> grade;
  r.grade_values.push_back(grade);
  input >> grade;
  r.grade_values.push_back(grade);
  input >> grade;
  r.grade_values.push_back(grade);
  return input;
}
```

The above code fragments will simplify your reading of the data file:

```
std::ifstream data_file;
//...
Record r;
std::vector<Record> database;
while (data_file >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

By modeling the text lines as records (classes), you avoid the nasty parallel arrays.  The design simplifies to one container (table) of records.

**Edit 1:  More grades**
You can expand the concept to handle more grades or variable number of grades by using `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  std::string record_text;
  std::getline(input, record_text);
  std::istringstream record_stream(record_text);
  record_stream >> r.first_name;
  record_stream >> r.last_name;
  int grade;
  while (record_stream >> grade)
  {
    r.grade_values.push_back(grade);
  }
  return input;
}
```

The above code reads a text line as a string.  Next, the string is converted to a stream.  The conversion allows for a loop to read in the grades.  The loop terminates after the last grade is read (and appended to the grades database).